# is there a way to sort functions in a scala class/ object by their names using scalafmt?

Tags: scala, sbt, scalafmt

I would like to sort the functions in the following objects alphabetically

```
object A {

def bfunc() = ???
def afunc() = ???

}
```

would get sorted to

```
object A {

def afunc() = ???
def bfunc() = ???

}
```

I tried to look through [scala fmt docs](https://scalameta.org/scalafmt/docs/configuration.html), no success